# awk assign field string to variable not working

Tags: bash, awk, sh

Just wondering why this is not working?

this is my awk code, converting "hh:mm:ss" format to seconds

```
  a.awk 
  3 BEGIN {                                                                         
  4     FS=":";                                                                     
  5 }                                                                               
  6                                                                                 
  7 {                                                                               
  8     retval = 0;                                                                 
  9     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                                                 
 10         retval += $i * 60 ** (NF-i);                                            
 11     }                                                                           
 12     print $retval;                                                                
 13 }                                                                               
 14                                                              

 input.txt
 59:22:40

 $ cat input.txt  | awk -f a.awk 
    //<empty>
 $
```

however, I try it on command line:

```
 $ echo "00:59:30" | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { retval = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {  retval += $i * 60 ** (NF-i); } print retval;}'                 
 3570
```

what's wrong with a.awk ?

---

update just for clarifcation

```
$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.0.1
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`: `awk -f a.awk < input.txt` saves spawning a process.

Comment: I don't see anything just looking at it, but I have two questions: (1) Why does your dump of `a.awk` start at line 3? (and I assume that those line number are a decoration for this post and not in the file itself, right?) and (2) does the command-line version work right if you send input from `input.txt`?

Comment: @dmckee try < input.txt still the same thing, no result...  for you question 1), yes, those line number is just for decoration. 2) yes, command line version works, which is 213760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `for` loop is cute, but this seems more direct and easier to understand.

```
BEGIN {
    FS=":";
}

{
    retval = 0;
    in_hours = $1
    in_minutes = $2;
    in_seconds = $3;
    retval = (in_hours * 3600) + (in_minutes * 60) + in_seconds
    print retval;
}
```

I think the problem with your loop is in the exponentiation. My version, at least, doesn't support any `**` operator. This might work better for you. Also, be careful with your dollar signs. You need them for fields; you don't need them for variables.

```
for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
    retval += i * (60^(NF-i));
}
```

Comment: I found http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html, ** and ^ is the same thing.  Thanks, I found the problem.... it was a typo... should return retval; not return $retval;

Answer (score 1):

Since your question has already been answered by the other 2 posts, here's something cute you can do with `date` to accomplish the same conversion from `hh:mm:ss` to time in seconds:

```
# GNU date

string_time="01:01:01"
string_time_in_seconds=$(date -u -d "1970-01-01 ${string_time}" +"%s")
echo ${string_time_in_seconds}

3661
```

Answer (score 0):

it was a typo

```
   a.awk 
    3 BEGIN {                                                                         
    4     FS=":";                                                                     
    5 }                                                                               
    6                                                                                 
    7 {                                                                               
    8     retval = 0;                                                                 
    9     for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {                                                 
   10         retval += $i * 60 ** (NF-i);                                            
   11     }                                                                           
   12     print retval;          ///<<<< notice here.                                                         
   13 }                                                                               
   14
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, using bash only:

```
IFS=: read -a a < input.txt
((retval=${a[0]}*3600+${a[1]}*60+${a[2]}))
echo "$retval"
```